# Strange Unicode Behaviour of TextField

Tags: java, javafx, unicode

**UPDATE June 20**

*Summary:*

Given the following:

```
String problemString = "é";
```

JavaFX8's TextField has trouble displaying the contents of problemString if it is set as follows:

```
aTextField.setText(problemString);
```

On Windows 10 the above with produce "МЃ" instead of "é", and on macOS 10.12 the TextField will display "é" but will be very buggy and effectively useless.

Also interesting to note is that the TextField has no problems with the contents of problemString being copied and pasted in on either operating system, only when using the setText() method.

**UPDATE June 12**

I have narrowed down the issue further. The é I am having problems with is not the precomposed é character (U+00E9) but rather is composed of e + ◌́.

Java will show these characters properly on macOS *but* the TextField is extremely glitchy and will not allow for editing of the text.

**ORIGINAL**

I have a program that reads in text, in unicode UTF-8 format, from a file and stores the content in String. At some point in the program the content of these strings is loaded into a TextField in order for the user to edit. My problem is that certain unicode characters are not display properly. However, if the text is saved back into a file, a new one or the old one, the content will be correct. Also to note, this happens only on Windows (10), on macOS (10.12) this problem does not occur. Any idea of what's causing this, or how to fix it?

For example:

I read in the character "é" from a text file and store it in a string. Upon displaying it in the TextField I will see "МЃ" and NOT "é". But, if I then continue with the program and save to a text file the file will have an "é" in it.

Comment: you should try changing the fonts. My be the font you are using not support the special character "é"

Comment: Probably this is an issue with the character encoding used. Try to specify correct encoding when reading/writing the file.

Comment: @Razib. Perhaps. I will give it a try, the font is currently set to "System". It just seems strange that it would not support "é" while supporting the far stranger "МЃ".

Comment: @fabian, Looking into this some more, something strange is going on with the character. If I copy and paste it straight from the file and check its unicode code (Using Swift) I get U+0065 (which is a normal e). Additionally, If i try to type it in this comment box and then delete it, the first attempt will remove its accent (leaving behind a normal e) and only the second will delete the character entirely.

Comment: You can try and first normalize the strings by using the `Normalizer` class in Java.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes. Yeah that's the comprise I've currently settled on (haven't updated this yet). The only drawback is that I am not sure if normalizing will always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the possible ways that unicode allows for characters to be stored. In this case the "é" has two ways of being represented.

**1. As a single unicode character, the composed form:**

é (U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE)

**2. As a a combination of two characters, the decomposed form:**

e (U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E)

◌́ (U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)

It appears that the TextField does not like displaying strings using the .setText() method if the string is in the decomposed form.

The way I got around this is by using the [Java Normalizer Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html).

```
String fixedString = Normalizer.normalize(problemString, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
aTextField.setText(fixedString);
```

The above code uses the Java Normalizer class in order to convert the problemString from its decomposed form to its composed form, this one the TextField seems to play nicely with.